# Align all 4 items in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have my timer that has date/hour/minute/seconds and the only one that doesn't align is the seconds. I tried many things such as different ways to align. So how can I align all the timer's items.
Can someone help me?

HTML

```
<div class="jumbotron timer">
  <h2>Time until the tracker is activated</h2>

  <div class="timertxtc">
    <div class="timertxt" id="daysBox"></div>
    <h4>Days</h4>
  </div>

  <h3 class="space">1</h3>

  <div class="timertxtc">
    <div class="timertxt" id="hoursBox"></div>
    <h4>Hours</h4>
  </div>

  <h3 class="space">1</h3>

  <div class="timertxtc">
    <div class="timertxt" id="minsBox"></div>
    <h4>Minutes</h4>
  </div>

  <h3 class="space">1</h3>

  <div class="timertxtc">
    <div class="timertxt" id="secsBox"></div>
    <h4>Seconds</h4>
  </div>

  <script>cdtd();</script>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient( 
    90deg,
    #FFFFFF, 
    #FFFFFF 18px,
    #CA1D20 0px, 
    #CA1D20 28px 
    );
}
h1{
  font-size: 64px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3498db;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #000;
}
h2{
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #3498db;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #000;
  margin: auto;
}
.jumbotron.timer{
  width: 48%;
  height: 360px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #669900;
}
.timertxt{
  color: #3498db;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #000;
  font-size: 64px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  border: 2px solid #2980b9 ;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #2980b9;
  text-align: center;

}
.space{
  font-size: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  visibility: hidden;
} 
.timertxtc{
  width: 25%;
  height: 120px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
}
h4{
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #3498db;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px #000;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character in your `<h3 class="space">1</h3>` elements was causing the content of the container div to exceed `100%` pushing 'seconds' on to the next line.

See fixes in the following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/oLncm9d2/4/

Instead of using an element for 'spacing' `padding-right / padding-left` in combination with `box-sizing: border-box;` can achieve the spacing you want, without disrupting width calculations.  (The solution demonstrates this and has removed the `<h3 class="space">1</h3>` elements.)

Note: I increased the container width to prevent excessive overlap for demonstration.

Comment: Thank you it did work. But now the h4 is not centred. What could i do to fix it?

Comment: fiddle has been updated, added 'text-align: center;'

Comment: here is another version of the fiddle with the elements completely balanced: https://jsfiddle.net/oLncm9d2/5/ (slightly different implementation, if it better suits your needs)